# Proving if $A^m=0$ then $\lambda =0 $ is the only eigenvalue of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A_{n\times n}$. Prove that if $A^m=0$ then $\lambda =0 $ is the only eigenvalue.

Since $A$ is not invertible (easy to show) then it has $\lambda = 0$ (also not hard to show) but how can I show that it's the only eigenvalue?

For all we know $A^k \neq 0$ for all $k$ up to $m-1$ so how can I know if there are no other $\lambda \neq 0$ to solve $det(\lambda I -A^{k})=0 , k\in[1,m)$ ?

Comment: Hint. Suppose $Av = \lambda v$. Calculate $A^2v$, $A^3v$ ...

Comment: Don't you mean since $A$ is not invertible it has eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: $A$ cannot be invertible, because then $A^m=0$ would be invertible.

Comment: Yes I meant not invertible.

Comment: @EthanBolker there could be more $n-1$ eigenvalues for $Av=\lambda v$ or more $n-1$ solutions for $|\lambda I -A|=0$, I don't see the pattern.

Comment: I think we have made a quiet assumption here that mm is finite? Because if mm goes to infinity, the eigenvalues don't have to be zero and yet $A^m$ could become the zero matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A.$ then there is $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax = \lambda x.$  now left multiply by $A$ repeatedly to get $$A^m x = \lambda ^m x = 0  $$  this implies $\lambda^m = 0$ which in turn gives $\lambda = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Calculate, in terms of $v$ and $\lambda$, $A^kv$ for $k=1,2,...,m$. Using that $A^m = 0$, what can you deduce about $\lambda$?